# determining the effect of the change in an independent variable using regression

Tags: r, regression, regression-coefficients, lm

I'm creating a regression model that predicts a customer's spending based on their income, while adjusting for age, gender , and region. The model looks as follows:

```
lm(spending ~ income + age + gender + region, data = tab.ordercustomers)
```

I want to see what the effect of an extra $10,000 of income is on spending. Would I do this by multiplying the income coefficient by 10,000?

Comment: Presuming the linear model is the correct model and that all the conditions necessary to apply lm() are fulfilled and that there are no other hidden confounders: yes.

Comment: @frank Why not add that as an answer? I'd also add that the income data should be in units of dollars (as opposed to thousands of dollars, for e.g.).

Comment: Do you want to do causal or predictive analysis?

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is correct. Maybe some points to consider are:

- You should be sure that the relation between your variables is indeed approximately linear in the range that is relevant for you.
- The `R` function `lm` presumes a couple of properties, like the independence of your measurements; check out the documentation and references therein.
- The variables `age`, `gender`, and `region` are confounders of `income` and `spending`, so controlling for those is the right thing to do. But you should think about whether there are further relevant confounders, i.e. variables that causally affect both `income` and `spending`.